# how to return an object through multi chained functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Hello there code wizards,

I am trying to get json data from the specified url down below and use it in a React component outside of the getWeather() function. What are the efficient ways to pass along an object from the innermost to outside? my console reads undefined. I believe there is an issue with variable scoping... Thanks for an idea to solve it.

Below is the code

```
function getWeather() {
    var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=3000,au';
    var apiKey= "005fa98ae858a29acf836ecdefac0411";
    var httpRequest;
    makeRequest();
    var response;


    function makeRequest() {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = responseMethod;
        httpRequest.open('GET', url + '&appid=' + apiKey);
        httpRequest.send();
    }

    function responseMethod() {
        if(httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if(httpRequest.status === 200) {
                updateUISucess(httpRequest.responseText);

            } else {

            }
        }
    }

    function updateUISucess(responseText) {
        return response = JSON.parse(responseText);
        // I would like to get this JSON object out so that it logs on the console.
    }

    return response;
};



console.log(getWeather());
```

Comment: Why can not you can getWeather and store it in state on react?

Comment: That was what I am aiming to do. However, I have no clue how to get the data out in the first place and pass it to getInitialState.

Comment: Since yours is a async call i would try `react-promise`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-promise

Answer (score 0):

Chrome, now allow return on you function, u need synchronous request. try node webkit for do you request.

Comment: I am indeed using Chrome now. How do I try node webkit?

Comment: I recomend this version, is good for programing. https://dl.nwjs.io/v0.12.2/nwjs-v0.12.2-win-ia32.zip

Comment: For build the request u need make a simple small app, with this powerfull runtime, here the easy start, http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Getting%20Started/

Comment: and after this u have create you index.html file on the same directory of this package, and add you script in you html, or add <script src="youscriptfilehere.js"></script>

Comment: this is important, add this line to you script file for see the developer tools,  
       require('nw.gui').Window.get().showDevTools();

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback method pattern to get the data and use it outside

```js
//Get weather function which accepts a callback function as a parameter
function getWeather(callback) {
  var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=3000,au';
  var apiKey = "005fa98ae858a29acf836ecdefac0411";
  var httpRequest;
  makeRequest();


  function makeRequest() {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = responseMethod;
    httpRequest.open('GET', url + '&appid=' + apiKey);
    httpRequest.send();
  }

  function responseMethod() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        try {
          //Parse response
          var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
          //Invoke callback function with first arg null and second with result
          callback(null, data);
        } catch (e) {
          //JSON parse failed
          //Invoke callback with first arg as error object
          callback(e)
        }
      } else {
      
       //Invoke callback with first arg as error object
        callback({
          success: false,
          status: httpRequest.status
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```js
function Weather(props) {
  return <p>{JSON.stringify(props.result)}</p>;
}

//Callback which accepts err and result
function handleResult(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    //Check for errors and return early if needed
    console.log("Error!", JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }
  //Assign to react state here
  console.log(result);
  const element = <Weather result ={result}/ > ;
  ReactDOM.render(
    element
  );

}

//Invoke getWeather with callback function as parameter
getWeather(handleResult);
```

Comment: can you give me an example of what might go inside the parenthesis of getWeather function for callback? thanks!

Comment: Have provided an example.. Scroll down to the end.. (the code snippet pane also scrolls)

Comment: Sorry I have taken a look at the last bit of code. I can't still comprehend what you mean by the first line: function getWeather(callback). Do I pass a callback function as a parameter?

Comment: Yup. You pass a function as the parameter. The function should accept two arguments: err and result. If the API weather call is successful and we have a result, the first argument (err) will be passed as null and the data will be in the result variable.

`getWeather(function(err,result){if(err){//handle error}else{//handle result}})`

The function passed to the method is invoked with the correct parameters once there is a result or error.

Comment: You can write code to update your react component with the new data or handle an error as the case may be. Have updated answer to clearly show invocation

Comment: It makes sense now to pass a function to another function to extract data.  How do you make use of data that is, sort of, trapped in the second function? I have tried defining a global variable and assigning the result passed to the callback to the variable. The console keeps saying the global variable is undefined. What is the most efficient way to pass the result to a React component and use it as its initial state? Do I create another callback function to extract the same data in the React component?

Comment: Will need to see more of your code to give you an exact answer. I have updated the answer using a modified version of hello world example from the react site

Comment: I have made the pulled data appear using ReactDOM.render(). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because of ajax (asynchronous) process js run continuously by line.
just make a callback function and pass it to calling function.

```js
function getWeather(cb) {
    var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=3000,au';
    var apiKey= "005fa98ae858a29acf836ecdefac0411";
    var httpRequest;
    makeRequest();
    var response;


    function makeRequest() {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = responseMethod;
        httpRequest.open('GET', url + '&appid=' + apiKey);
        httpRequest.send();
    }

    function responseMethod() {
        if(httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if(httpRequest.status === 200) {
                updateUISucess(httpRequest.responseText);

            } else {

            }
        }
    }

    function updateUISucess(responseText) {
       // return 
      response = JSON.parse(responseText);
        // I would like to get this JSON object out so that it logs on the console.
     cb(response);
    }

    return response;
};


getWeather(cb);

function cb(res){ 
   alert(res);
   console.log(res);
}
```